# Search function with a foreign API in MVC architechture

Tags: c#, visual-studio, model-view-controller

I am trying to mess around with a foreign API, but i cant seem to get the last bit working. I have succesfully retrieved data from the API but i cannot get the search functionality to cooperate with the API. The search function needs an id, and from that an object is returned. Here is what i have so far:

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetCardsByID(string idNumber)
    {
        //idNumber = "c353618d9f76c03a0c7d549f2d877f9533112d0c";
        ViewBag.Message = "Your GetCardsByID page.";
        var client = new RestClient("https://api.magicthegathering.io");
        var request = new RestRequest("v1/cards/{id}", Method.GET);
        request.AddUrlSegment("id", idNumber);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var content = response.Content;
        CardContainer cards = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CardContainer>(content);

        return View();
    }
```

**View**

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "GetCardsByID";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

<p>
  In this tab we can retrieve a card by searching with an id
</p>

<form method="get" action="@Url.Action("GetCardsByID", "CardsController")">
  <label for="idNumber">Search</label>
  <input type="text" name="idNumber" id="idNumber" />
  <button type="submit">Perform search</button>
</form>
```

**Routing**

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = 
            UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**The error i get is as follows: (Translated)**

Server error in program'/'.
Resource not found.
**Description:** HTTP 404, the resource you are looking for, or one of its dependencies, has possible been removed and is not accesable at this moment. Check if the following URL-addresses are spelled correctly
**Wanted URL address:** */CardsController/GetCardsByID*

[Home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70eIc.png) [GetCardsByID page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWHhg.png) [Search error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDgz6.png)

Comment: are you getting some error? what response do you get?

Comment: What does "cannot get the search functionality to cooperate with the API" mean? As it is we'd need magic to understand what your actual issue is

Comment: What is the actual problem? [Here](https://api.magicthegathering.io/v1/cards/c353618d9f76c03a0c7d549f2d877f9533112d0c) everything is working fine.

Comment: Sorry i forgot the error message. I have edited it in now

Comment: Seems to me that you did not map the Route correctly?

Comment: @Renuiz has kindly posted a functioning URL. I note that if I chop a few characters off the end (i.e. pass an invalid ID), I get a 404 error (inside some JSON). So if you use the ID in this URL `c353618d9f76c03a0c7d549f2d877f9533112d0c` in your web app, what do you get? Use F12 tools to determine what URL is actually being submitted.

Comment: @Tvt I have added my routing class.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have submitted 3 pictures that show the error. I think my problem lies with the routing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call a controller, don't put controller on the end of it.

Try this:

```
<form method="get" action="@Url.Action("GetCardsByID", "Cards")">
  <label for="idNumber">Search</label>
  <input type="text" name="idNumber" id="idNumber" />
  <button type="submit">Perform search</button>
</form>
```

Note the Url.Action is `Cards`, not `CardsController`

Even though your controller is called `CardsController.cs`

You know you could probably do this easier entirely in javascript